# Windows 2008 R2 freezing when more than two VMs started

Tags: windows, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, xeon

I have an interesting problem. I am runnnig ESXi 4.0 Update 1. Windows 2008 R2 runs fine with VMWare tools (without the SVGA driver). Once I start a second Windows 2008 R2 server, they randomly lockup for 30 seconds or more. Ping becomes unresponsive.

I cannot work out what this is. I've tried different network adapters (2, 3, e1000), all have the same issue. Same with GFX card driver.

I'm really at a loss. I have 2xWindows 2003 R2 servers running on this machine fine. Start up one 2008 R2 box, fine, second one, bam. VMs freezing.

HW is: HP DL360 G5, Xeon, 10GB memory, raid 5.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the configuration of the VM's? How many vCPU's vs the no of physical cores on the host. How much RAM are you configuring in the VM's? When this happens is the VI Client still responsive or is the Host also under pressure? Are these VM's clones of each other?

Comment: Do you have hyper-v services installed on either of the 2008 VMs?

Comment: Does it happen with all "second" VMs or is it a specific one?  Also, if you watch the performance graphs for the host during the lockup do you see anything plateau?  I had a VM that had an application that would eat up the CPU time at boot at it messed up the other VMs on that box.  We ended up moving them back to physical servers.

Answer (score 0):

Smells like either a host driver issue, or simply said broken hardware. I would boot into a memory tester. The host, not the vms.